# Vaadin change view's route dynamically using selected tab

Tags: java, routes, tabs, vaadin

I am wondering if it's possible to change dynamically view's route using the `Tabs` component and `getSelectedTab()` method.

##### Here is a simple example

I have a View with `@Route("settings")` which is responsible for changing settings. Inside this view I have some `Tabs`, so I want for selected tab to be changed also the View's route.

- For first tab, the route should remain `/settings`
- Starting with second tab, route should change like this `/settings/{tabName}`

```
@PermitAll
@PageTitle("Settings")
@Route(value = "settings", layout = MainLayout.class)
public class SettingsView extends Main {

    private final Tab profile;
    private final Tab password;
    private final Tab notifications;
    private final VerticalLayout content;

    public SettingsView() {
        addClassName("page-content");
        profile = new Tab("Profile");
        notifications = new Tab("Profile");
        password = new Tab("Password");

        Tabs tabs = new Tabs(profile, password, notifications);
        tabs.addSelectedChangeListener(
                event -> setContent(event.getSelectedTab()));

        tabs.setOrientation(Tabs.Orientation.VERTICAL);
        content = new VerticalLayout();
        setContent(tabs.getSelectedTab());

        HorizontalLayout hLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
        hLayout.add(tabs, content);
        hLayout.setSpacing(true);

        add(hLayout);
    }

    private void setContent(Tab tab) {
        content.removeAll();

        if (tab.equals(profile)) {
            content.add(new ProfileTab());
        } else if (tab.equals(password)) {
            content.add(new PasswordTab());
        } else {
            content.add(new NotificationsTab());
        }
    }

}
```

###### Example of displayed tab

```
public class ProfileTab extends Div {

    // html elements defined

    public ProfileTab() {
        // adding elements defined
    }

}
```

##### So using the class above, the conditions should be like this:

When users selects one of these tabs, the route changes also

- ProfileTab -> route = `/settings` - (not changing because it's first)
- PasswordTab -> route = `/settings/password`
- NotificationsTab -> route = `/settings/notifications`

Comment: Did you take a look at the official cookbook? https://cookbook.vaadin.com/tabs-with-routes/a

Comment: Thanks, your solution is almost perfect, excepting that I don't know how can I don't add route link for first tab as I want it to be still `/settings`, and not `/settings/profile`